# CMake (CLion / Android Studio) Sub-builds fail with ninja

Tags: android-studio, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide, ninja

I have multiple dependencies for a piece of software. To make everything easier, we made CMake build files for these dependencies. For example, we have lo `libfoo`, so we make a folder called "make", and in there put the file "buildLibFoo.cmake", which looks like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)

externalproject_add(LIBFOO
        URL https://github.com/lib/foo/archive/refs/tags/v1.6.0.tar.gz
        URL_MD5 58e4e09322f2d1e417469eb0987f0531b
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 0
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/libfoo
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/libfoo/src/libfoo
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND
        cd <SOURCE_DIR> &&
        autoreconf -i &&
        ./configure 
        BUILD_COMMAND
        cd <SOURCE_DIR> &&
        make -j$(nproc)
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        )


set(LIBFOO_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/libfoo/src/libfoo/utils)
set(LIBFOO_LIB_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/libfoo/src/libfoo/utils/.libs)
```

In my primary CMakeFiles.cmake I add the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project("testproject")

set (COMPILE_FLAGS "-O2")

## Need LIBFOO
if(NOT (${LIBFOO_INCLUDE_PATH} AND ${LIBFOO_LIB_PATH}))
    include(buildTSS.cmake)
    include_directories(${LIBFOO_INCLUDE_PATH})
    link_directories(${LIBFOO_LIB_PATH})
    list(APPEND DEPENDENCY_LIST "LIBFOO")
endif()

add_library( 
        testproject
        SHARED
        testproject.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testproject libfoo)    
add_dependencies(testproject ${DEPENDENCY_LIST})
```

While the compiles fine if I run `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and `make`, it fails to do so if I use Android Studio (with native code) or CLion. Here is an example in Android Studio.

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/derp/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /home/derp/AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/.cxx/Debug/565m494g/arm64-v8a testproject}
ninja: Entering directory `/home/derp/AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/.cxx/Debug/565m494g/arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: build.ninja:178: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)
```

Any ideas how to make it work through the IDE?

Comment: Perhaps it's the `make -j$(nproc)` in the `externalproject_add` command that spooks Ninja? Perhaps as a viable workaround you could tell CMake to use the makefile generator in your IDE's (since makefiles seems to work)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - it was the "j$(nproc)" that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same error for an existing project I was trying to load with CLion that also built fine using `cmake` from the command line.

In my case the solution was to override the default setting CLion uses for the generator tool (ninja) and set it to the "Let CMake decide"

[image: Screen shot of CLion preferences > Build > CMake - set generator drop down to Let CMake decide]

Comment: It worked for me too, my google test were not using the last version of my simple library (Windows 11)